# Report interval date column issue - M2

Tags: magento2, grid, reports, date, statistics

Admin panel > Reports > Products > Ordered[image]

It's magento's default report and result data is showing in 3rd date  it's actually of 4th date.

Issue is, Data is showing in one day previous in grid.

Can any one help for "**Interval**" date issue!...